DepositRateHelper vs SwapRateHelper vs FraRateHelper in QuantLib
I'm new to QuantLib and am trying to build a term structure for a vanilla IRS. I understand that QuantLib provides several helper functions like DepositRateHelper, SwapRateHelper, and FraRateHelper to help with this, but I'm not entirely sure when to use each one.
From what I’ve gathered online:

For short tenors (in days), I should use DepositRateHelper
For middle-length tenors (in months), use FraRateHelper
For longer tenors (more than 1 year), use SwapRateHelper

Is this understanding correct? For instance, in the Bloomberg screenshot below, would I use FraRateHelper for the month tenors (1MO-11MO) and SwapRateHelper for the longer tenors (12MO-50YR)?
Could someone explain what's happening behind these functions and clarify when each should be used?
Thank you!


Could someone provide some insights? Thanks!

Deposits, FRA and swaps are different instruments; you can get better definitions of them by searching than those I could write here.  Each instrument is priced differently, and each of DepositRateHelper, SwapRateHelper and FraRateHelper does the specific calculation for the relevant instrument.
So no, it's not just a matter of maturity; if, for instance, the quote you're getting is for a swap, you'll have to use SwapRateHelper even if the tenor is short.
Also, SwapRateHelper refers to old-style vanilla swaps paying LIBOR vs a fixed rate.  I see "term SOFR" in your image, so I'm guessing that these are OIS instead, which means you'll need OISRateHelper.  I can't be sure, though, since I don't read Chinese.
